# How to send log to url with nlogger in winform c#.?

Tags: c#, winforms, logging

> For ex I want to see every logs  of my ATM in my dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read up on their documentation. NLog supports a HTTP Target to which logs can be posted:

[NLog HTTP Target](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/HTTP-target)